# います and あります usage

Tags: usage, meaning

I just learned about: `います` and `あります`.

I know I should use `います` for people and moving things and `あります` for plants and inanimate things.

I have two doubts:

- Which one should I use with "dead body". For example: "Is there a dead body inside the room?"
- What about robots or a non living thing with AI?

Comment: Other questions on which verb to use, but not answering this specific question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/when-is-it-okay-to-use-あります-with-a-living-subject and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/do-viruses-あります-or-います

Comment: If you are just starting out, then those rules will often get you by. However, the topic is more complex and depends on one's perspective, feeling, and context. Here is an informative read on the topc: http://leo.aichi-u.ac.jp/~goken/bulletin/pdfs/NO22/03Yamamoto.indd.pdf

Comment: @Dono: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I am far from understanding a text like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically it depends on how the speaker feels. However, I think we usually say:

- 死体があります。
- ロボットがいます。 if it looks like it has a mind of its own.
- ロボットがあります。  if it is an industrial robot without a mind.
- 車がいます。 if it is being driven by a human.
- 車があります。 when we talk about cars in general.
- 人工知能（AI）があります。 if it doesn't have anything visual, auditory or physical.
- コンピュータのソフトウェアがあります。
- ゲームのキャラクターがいます。  if it is controlled by computer software.
- 細菌/ウイルス/コンピュータウイルスがいます。 when we talk about someone's symptoms.
- 細菌/ウイルス/コンピュータウイルスがあります。
- ゾンビがいます。
- 幽霊がいます。

Comment: +1. I never knew that things are this way: "車がいます。 if it is being driven by a human.". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to a quick google search, and agreeing with my thoughts, you should say "死体があります" for dead body, but you would say "死んだ人がいます" (if you like zombies).

For robots and AI, well, I guess います is acceptable, provided it's like a living thing (such as an aibo). I doubt you'd say it for a clever car, unless it's KITT from the Knight Rider…  To sum up, it's quite subjective in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you said: there is a fish that is died on the table。

> います or あります。
>
> 例：机に魚がいます。　（でも魚は死んだ。）