# Usage of ある with animate things

Tags: word-choice, verbs, grammar

I was going through some other uses of the verb ある and then, I came across the use of ある with animate object. 
Following are the statements of the book which I am referring to.

1. If we indicate the idea of possession in context of close human relationships like family, we can still use ある. E.g. 私は子供がある - I have children. Whereas, if we use it for other human relationship it is wrong, E.g. 私は先生がある.
2. However, if we indicate the idea of existence then  ある cannot be used. E.g. 山田さんは母がもない - Yamada-san does not have his mother now.

As, we know if the following sentence emphasizes possession it can be used with ある, whereas, if it conveys existence it cannot be used with ある. So my question is, if I use negative form of ある (be it plain or polite), will it indicate possession or existence. Eg. 私は子供がありません- I don't have children. In this statement, as per me, it is indicating more existence (like I don't have children, rather than possession)

Edit: Here is the photograph (Point 5 & 6) [image]

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1905/1628 (answer by user458) and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6474/1628 Do these answer your question?

Comment: I saw those articles, but I have doubt regarding the where it is ossession or existence in negative form of ある. Which is not covered by those articles

Comment: The usages 子供がある or 母がもうない are a little archaic but still valid. And this is an exact duplicate question of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/aru-vs-iru-why-is-aru-in-watakushi-wa-untenshu-ga-aru-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%af%e9%81%8b%e8%bb%a2%e6%89%8b%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-unacceptabl