# Sentence ending with でもあった

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-も

I found this sentence on a visual novel, and it's the first time I see でも+あった　at the end of a phrase, what does it mean?

This is the sentence:

> だがその偶然はあらかじめ決められていた世界の意志**でもあった**。

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: See answers on this question:  [When is it okay to use あります with a living subject?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1905/78).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually speaking でもあった is what you get by trying to combine だった and も (as in "also").

だった is a contraction of であった and you have to use the uncontracted form in order to insert も after で.

So で**も**あった means "it **also** was".

(In the non-past tense, the same thing happens: "だ + も = でもある".)